# Is it faster to compare two object.attribute or two object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object date as follow

```
let date = {
   string: '2018-10-09'
}

I also have two hour object :

let hour1 = {
   string: '09:00',
   date: date
}

let hour2 = {
   string: '10:00',
   date: date
}
```

I want to check if EITHER hour1.date is equal to hour2.date OR if hour1.date.string is equal to hour2.date.string. What is fastest between the two, and why ?:

```
if (hour1.date === hour2.date) //do things
if (hour1.date.string === hour2.date.string) //do things
```

**EDIT - Partial Answer**

Ok so I've made a test as follows :

```
let date = {
   string: '2018-10-09'
}

let hour1 = {
   string: '09:00',
   date: date
}

let hour2 = {
   string: '10:00',
   date: date
}

var iterations = 100000000


console.time('Object comparison');
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    compareObjects(hour1.date, hour2.date);
};
console.timeEnd('Object comparison');


console.time('Property comparison');
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    compareObjectsProperties(hour1.date.string, hour2.date.string);
}
console.timeEnd('Property comparison');


function compareObjects(o1, o2) {
    if (o1 === o2) return true;
}

function compareObjectsProperties(prop1, prop2) {
    if (prop1 === prop2) return true;
}
```

Output :

```
Object comparison: 284.808837890625ms
Property comparison: 281.16796875ms
```

Comment: up to sample code you can just skip checking. it will always be true. if in real life you _don't set_ `date:date` then specify what type of `date` property is.

Comment: I would expect that comparing `hour1.date` would be faster, but those two comparisons are not equivalent. The first is a reference comparison and the second is a value comparison.

Comment: I know comparisons are not equivalent, I should have be more precise in the question. I just wanted to know if comparing an object was faster than comparing attributes of this object.

Answer (score 2):

alternatives are not equal at all:

```
var a = {
   str: 'aaa'
}, b = {
   str: 'aaa'
};

// true, strings are not equal
a.str === b.str; 
/*
  false, both objects are independent and so are different; 
  nested properties does not matter
*/
a === b;
```